# Adding and removing fields with conditions on click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

JavaScript rookie here..

I am trying to build a form where I have a certain field that I want people to be able to add more of up to 4 fields. I think I managed to do that part (although probably very clunky code) but I dont know how to make the remove function work. The challenge is that when somebody clicks on the minus sign, I want to delete the last field created and that last field only.

Thanks for your help!

HTML:

```
<form action="">
    <div class="form-element">
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="" placeholder="Full Legal Name">
    </div>

    <h3>Broker Principal(s)</h3>
    <div class="form-element">
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="" placeholder="Broker Principal">
    </div>
    <div class="form-element" id="addField">
    </div>
    <i id="add" class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i>
    <i id="add" class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x hidden minus"></i>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var plus = document.getElementById("add");
var minus = document.querySelector(".minus");
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var counter = 2;
var field = document.getElementById("addField");

plus.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(counter !== 0){
        field.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<div id="bp' + counter + '" class="form-element fadeOutIn">' + '<input type="text" name="Broker Principal ' + counter + '" id="" placeholder="Broker Principal ' + counter + '">' + "</div>");
        minus.classList.remove("hidden");
        counter = (counter + 1) % array.length;
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
font-size: 17px;
}

input {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.form-element {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px 0;
}

i {
    color: #FDB813;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

i:hover {
   color: #FEC849; 
}

@keyframes fadeOutIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  50% {opacity: 0.4;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fadeOutIn {
  animation-name: fadeOutIn;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
 }

 .hidden {
     display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
minus.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var form = document.getElementById('addField');
    form.removeChild(form.childNodes[form.childNodes.length-1]); 
}
```